# Jquery CDN not working on blogger

Tags: jquery, cdn

I am trying to add following code to my blog. It is having jquery CDN. it is working fine on my machine but not working in my blogger. This is Color Scheme generator which is already posted on my blog [Color Scheme Generator](http://techisquest.blogspot.in/2013/04/color-scheme-generator.html). I was just trying to test its initial version on my blog.

```
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
#red, #green, #blue {
          float: left;
           clear: left;
            width: 300px;
             margin: 15px;
       }
       #swatch {
               width: 120px;
                height: 100px;
                  margin-top: 18px;
              margin-left: 350px;
                background-image: none;
         }
       #red .ui-slider-range { background: #ef2929; }
        #red .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #ef2929; }
        #green .ui-slider-range { background: #8ae234; }
            #green .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #8ae234; }
            #blue .ui-slider-range { background: #729fcf; }
             #blue .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #729fcf; }
       </style>
     <script>
  function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
     var hex = [r.toString( 16 ),g.toString( 16 ),b.toString( 16 )];
        $.each( hex, function( nr, val ) {
                if ( val.length === 1 ) {
                        hex[ nr ] = "0" + val;
           }
            });
         return hex.join( "" ).toUpperCase();
         }
     function refreshSwatch() {
       var red = $( "#red" ).slider( "value" ),
        green = $( "#green" ).slider( "value" ),
         blue = $( "#blue" ).slider( "value" ),
         hex = hexFrom RGB( red, green, blue );
            $( "#swatch" ).css( "background-color", "#" + hex );
         color_match();
      }
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $( "#red, #green, #blue" ).slider({
         orientation: "horizontal",
         range: "min",
          max: 255,
         value: 127,
        slide: refreshSwatch
         });
       $( "#red" ).slider( "value", 255 );
        $( "#green" ).slider( "value", 140 );
            $( "#blue" ).slider( "value", 60 );
       refreshSwatch();
        });
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function rgbToHex(R,G,B) {return toHex(R)+toHex(G)+toHex(B)}
        function toHex(n) {
              n = parseInt(n,10);
             if (isNaN(n)) return "00";
         n = Math.max(0,Math.min(n,255));
             return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n-n%16)/16) + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n%16);
     }

   function color_match()
  {
          var red,green,blue;
            red = $( "#red" ).slider( "value" );
           green = $( "#green" ).slider( "value" );
        blue = $( "#blue" ).slider( "value" );

        var rm,gm,bm;
         var str="";
            var i=0;
            var j=0;
 for(j=0;j<=9;j++)
 {
        rm=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        gm=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        bm=Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        str=str+"<table>";
        str=str+"<tr>";
        var k;
         k=2;
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
          {
            rm = (rm+red)/k;
              gm = (gm+green)/k;
            bm = (bm+blue)/k;
         var bgcolor="";
             bgcolor=rgbToHex(rm,gm,bm);

             str=str+"<td id='swatch' style='background-color:#"+bgcolor+";width: 80px; height: 40px; '>&nbsp;&nbsp;#"+bgcolor+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";

   }
        str=str+"</tr>";
   str=str+"</table>";
     str=str+"<br />";

    }
  $( "#color_seq" ).html(str);
}
</script>
<br />
<div id="red">
</div>
<div id="green">
</div>
<div id="blue">
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="swatch">
</div>
<br />
<input id="color_gen" onclick="color_match();" type="button" value="Generate" />
 <br />
<div id="color_seq">
</div>
```

Its working fine on my local machine but I am not able to figure out why this is not working on blogger.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Does your blog include jQuery already, or any other libraries that would overwrite `$`?

Comment: When working with Google Chrome you can use the Developer Tools console to see what error you get

Comment: It was a simple issue. Some string were not properly working now changed and are working fine.